# Get all available keyboards (languages) of the user

Tags: java, android, input

Example for clarity, on many devices, when you long press the "space" key, you can select the input language from the previously selected ones. How to get these languages?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534958/android-get-available-input-languages